# How to print on the console when using inplace=True?

Tags: python

When `for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=True)` is used, any `print` command will print within the text file, instead of on the console. But I want to use `print` to debug. So how to achieve printing onto the consolel after `for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=True)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inplace=True` argument to `fileinput.input` effectively redirects standard output to the file you are reading from. You can specify a *different* file to write to with `print` using the `file` keyword argument.

```
import sys
import fileinput


for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=True):
    print("new content")
    print("debugging", file=sys.stderr)
```

If you start with

```
a
b
c
```

then your file will look like

```
a
new content
b
new content
c
new content
```

after this loop runs, and you'll see

```
debugging
debugging
debugging
```

writtent to standard error.